# Is it possible to change button postbackurl via javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a sever control button.
Is it possible to set postbackurl of the button via javascript?

```
<asp:Button name="Button1" ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search"  OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="return searchSubmit();" PostBackUrl="" >
```

Comment: In javascript funtion, I have added document.getElementById("Button1").PostBackUrl = "example.aspx"; It didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

By default, any asp.net page will automatically have it's own form tag that posts to its self.
In javascript, you can change the action of the form to post to any other page you want.

So you could update the form's action when you click the button, and it will then post to the updated action.

e.g. with some jquery

```
$(function(){
    $('#btnsubmit').click(function(){
        $('#myform').attr("action", "updatedurl.aspx");
    });
});
```